# Disable same-origin policy on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to disable the [same-origin policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome extensions? Yes, but you must ask for proper permissions. You linked to description how to do it.

In web pages? No, that's the point of this protection.